# Find patients who are consistently above the average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

Each cust_id has a value for every quarter in 2019. I graph the dataframe to show the value over time for each customer. The graph looks like this:

[image]

The red line is the average values for each time period for all the customers. Here is the code I used to create this graph:

```
over_time = df.pivot_table(index='cust_id',columns='date_id',values='trx_unt', fill_value=0)
over_time = over_time.reset_index(level=0)
df_m = pd.melt(over_time, id_vars=['cust_id'])

# Create an average line to compare
df_m['date_id'] = df_m['date_id'].astype('str')
agg = df_m.groupby('date_id').agg('mean').reset_index()


#graph each cust as a line and compare to average
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
for name, group in df_m.groupby('cust_id'):
    group.plot('date_id', y='value', ax=ax, legend=None, color = 'c')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
agg.plot('date_id', y='value',ax=ax, legend=None, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

GOAL: I want to find the cust_id's that were consistently over the red line or above average for every time period.

I am not sure how to approach this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Attach to every time period the average, then grouping by customer, flagging only those elements which all were above the average, and then querying on that.

It might look something like this:

```
df = df.merge(time_data, on='time', how='left', validate='m:1')
df['gt_mean'] = df['value'] > df['average']
df['select'] = df.groupby('customer')['gt_mean'].all()

df.query('select == 1')
```

Comment: `apply` and `eval` are generally discouraged.

Comment: `apply` I get. `eval` though? What are your thoughts on https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html ?

Comment: IHMO, `eval` is dangerous as it might create unexpected output if string is not parsed correctly. Not to mention it's usually harder to debug when that happens. I may well be wrong though.

Comment: Regardless, it can be rewritten to put the calculations outside the groupby